# expanding a current database

Tags: sql-server, database-design, schema

I am rewriting a server program. currently the program has order batching and orders.
(currently written in winforms with mssql database with no orm- to be rewritten as a blazor server app with mssql database using dapper orm)

tables
batch - batchid, datetime
order- orderid, batchid, ordernumber, price, qty, productid, location

the customer wants to convert the program to add individual pieces rather than orders. 
my problem is they have a customer that recycles ordernumbers every 2 years so i can not use the ordernumber to track the order.. 
would it be best practice  to just change the order table to order item and add an additional order table?

tables
batch - batchid, datetime
order - orderid, batchid
orderitem- orderitemid, orderid, ordernumber, price, qty, productid, location

i am open to hearing better ways.
1 order with 7 items of the same type
what i am expecting to get from this..
table 1 batch
1 row(batchid 1,time.now)
table 2 orders
1 row(batchid 1,orderid 1)
table 3 orderItems
7 rows
(orderitemid 1, orderid 1, ordernumber, price, qty, productid,location)
(orderitemid 2, orderid 1, ordernumber, price, qty, productid,location)
(orderitemid 3, orderid 1, ordernumber, price, qty, productid,location)
(orderitemid 4, orderid 1, ordernumber, price, qty, productid,location)
(orderitemid 5, orderid 1, ordernumber, price, qty, productid,location)
(orderitemid 6, orderid 1, ordernumber, price, qty, productid,location)
(orderitemid 7, orderid 1, ordernumber, price, qty, productid,location)
the reason for the breakdown to single pieces is for job cost and employee time tracking per piece..as well as qc tracking.

Comment: Requirements are too vague to give informed answer. Most applications that deal with :Orders" do have a master Order table and then an OrderItem table to store individual products but usually the customer Order Number would be on the Order table as it relates to the order not to each product. But again I don't understand your data model.

Comment: i agree.. but this is a manufacturing company that only scans in the order numbers that there customers provide.. they have no nor want a in house order number. there position is that it saves on printing pages to go with there orders.. a fact that makes my life interesting to say the least, especially with there main customer recycling order numbers every 2 years. if anyone has any example of a db that batches orders and tracks pieces instead of full orders i would love to take a look. will edit example to show more what i mean.

Comment: If they are storing it in a database there will inevitably be a key. You're in control of the design of the database. Surely it's trivial enough to have an order number when you couple  them with something like a period of time that would be a key for the order. You  should be able to design a solution to cater for this requirement. What would happen if suppliers had the same order id? simply put you would also have a supplier ID that would form part of the key for the record. In this case you need to be more granular.

Comment: making it work is really not the problem.. my concern is making it work well and reliably.  my question above was is there a better way?..  I am in no way a db architect. I am just a code monkey.  so I humbly come here and ask again.. is the above considered best practice for the small example or is there a better way.. if there is I am happy to research and test any ideas that are posted.  thanks you all!